# Does IIS7 use different default membership provider?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7, asp.net-membership

Say I create *CreateUserWizard* control and use  *AspNetSqlMembershipProvider* (defined in *machine.config*) as a default membership provider. Assuming I change default provider's *requiresQuestionAndAnswer* attribute to *false*, then *CreateUserWizard* control template should not be required to provide *Question* and *Answer* fields. But if I request the page via *IIS7* I get the following exception:

> CreateUserWizard1: CreateUserWizardStep.ContentTemplate does not contain an IEditableTextControl with ID Question for the security question, this is required if your membership provider requires a question and answer.

A) The above exception suggests that when requesting a page via *IIS7*, runtime doesn’t use *AspNetSqlMembershipProvider* (defined in *machine.config*)as a default provider?! If true, then why is that?

B) And where can I find the definition for *IIS7’s* default provider?

thanx

EDIT:

Here is `<Membership>` element in machine.config file:

```
    <membership>
     <providers>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web,Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
         connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" 
         enablePassswordRetrieval="false" 
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
         applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
         passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
         minRequiredPasswordLength="7" 
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
         passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
         passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
    </providers>
   </membership>
```

> Are you changing the `machine.config` for the correct version of runtime?

I'm not sure what you mean by that. I'm running Asp.Net 3.5, which I think uses Asp.Net engine version 2.0.50727. Thus I manipulated machine.config located inside  *C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS7 uses its own configuration file located at `%windir%\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config`. However, this file deals with IIS7 specific configuration (e.g. `<system.webServer>`) and not `<system.web>` stuff. I believe those are still read from `machine.config` and `web.config` files. Indeed, the default value (specified in `machine.config`) for `requiresQuestionAndAnswer` for the `AspNetSqlMembershipProvider` is `true` on my machine.

**UPDATE:**

Under a 64 bit OS, a .NET application can either run on a 32 bit CLR in WOW64 mode or natively run under x64 mode. Each .NET framework instance has its own set of config files and ignores all other configuration files.

IIS7 on a 64 bit OS runs applications in 64 bit mode by default. You can, however, set an application pool to run as a 32 bit WOW64 process (`enable32BitAppOnWin64`, which you can set in Advanced Settings dialog for an application pool in IIS7 manager). If you do that, obviously it'll use settings from 32 bit `machine.config`. The reason VS Web server uses 32 bit `machine.config` is exactly this: it runs as a WOW64 process.

Comment: Any idea why on my machine default provider ( defined inside machine.config ) is ignored?

Comment: SourceC: Could you post the <membership> tag in your machine.config? Are you changing the `machine.config` for the correct version of runtime?

Comment: hi - my reply is in the original post, which I edited. I appreciate it

Comment: SourceC: Are you running a 64 bit OS?

Comment: Yes, I'm running 64 bit Windows server 2008 (trial version). Is that of any significance?

Comment: Yep, Change the `machine.config` file in "%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG" and test.

Comment: Yay, it works now. :D In case you're still reading this:A) why do the two servers ( IIS7 and VS's build-in server ) use two different machine.config files? B) And more importantly, when requesting a page via IIS7, does runtime only use settings in machine.config for 64bit version or does it also "borrow" certain settings from machine.config for 32bit version? In any case, I really appreciate your help

Comment: SourceC: I've updated the answer. B) The 32 bit machine.config is completely ignored in 64 bit mode.

Answer (score 1):

Where exactly did you make the change on "requiresQuestionAndAnswer"? If it is on machine.config, IIS should honor that.

Comment: I made the change in machine.config

Answer (score 1):

You added `requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"` in the `<membership>` provider, you should also change it in the `<profile>` one, just add the `<profile>` element and set  `requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"` on its provider